# Align x axis in a graph

Tags: python, pandas

How can I align the time on the x axis? I want to see all the data over the day.

[image]

The data is collected any time of the day.

Comment: can you provide the code you have so far?

Comment: trying adding arg `sharex=True` if using subplots ..?

Comment: @ChrisA No i can't, i'm new with pandas and data analysis.
I try.

Comment: @CrisA Thanks for this suggestion i'll try it and works, but my problem is that the data changes every day and i want some that array is something constant, that not changes with the data. the data have to adjust on my x axis that is hours of a day